# Long integer overflow error and resolution

Tags: python, optimization, python-2.7

I am writing a program that gives me an overflow error. I realized that the cause of that was due to my input which could do inputs till 2147483646. I figured this using the sys.maxint. Anything beyond that gave me an overflow error. How I can take in inputs for large values? For value, 2147483646 my system hangs. How to deal with such an error. The statement of the problem here is given, A number is called lucky if the sum of its digits, as well as the sum of the squares of its digits is a prime number. How many numbers between A and B are lucky?

I am attaching the sample code here.

```
class luckynumbers():
    #required numbers are only 0-9, their values can be stored in a lookup table
    def __init__(self):
            self.squarelist=[0,1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81]

    def isEven(self, n):
            if n%2 ==0:
                    return True
            else:
                    return False

    def isPrime(self,n):
            return_val=True
            if n==2:
                    return_val= True
            if not self.isEven(n):
                    for i in xrange(2,n/2):
                            if n%i ==0:
                                    return_val=False
                                    break
            else:
                    return_val= False
            return return_val

    def sumofDigits(self,n):
            return sum(map(int, n))

    def generateSquares(self, n):
            return map(lambda x: self.squarelist[x], map(int,n))

    def satisfy(self,n):
            return self.isPrime(self.sumofDigits(n)) and self.isPrime(sum(self.generateSquares(n)))

def main():
    luckyno=luckynumbers()
    t=int(raw_input().rstrip())
    count = []
    for i in xrange(t):
            counts = 0
            a,b = map(int, raw_input().rstrip().split())
            if a==1:
                    a=2
            for j in xrange(a,b+1,1):
                     if luckyno.satisfy(str(j)):
                            counts+=1
            count.append(counts)
    for i in count:
            print i

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

I am still looking at long integers document in python. But haven't figured a way yet. I have tried to use optimization as far as I can think of. Anything more, I will really grateful.

Comment: If you use Python 3.x, all numbers are longs automatically, so this'll just work. In 2.x, use longs instead - they auto-promote to bignumber style implementations which will allow for insanely massive numbers (albeit with reduced performance). To get a long literal, just have `L` after the number: `20L` is a long. You can also use the `long()` built-in.

Comment: Please give us a traceback (or at least a line number) where the OverflowError occurs.  If it's at an `xrange()` call, then yes, it's a known limitation.  Note that such loops would take forever to run more than 2.7 billion times anyway.

Comment: It happens at the point, for j in xrange(a,b+1,1) line on the code. When I change int to long, the code works albeit takes 10 seconds to perform the task. Any suggestions on improving this will be great.

Answer (score 0):

The `xrange()` function is limited to ints (not longs).  The code works as expected if you replace the `xrange()` call where OverflowError occurs with just a `range()` call.